# How to send a command containing an apostrophe in teraterm

Tags: apostrophe, teraterm

I am trying to send the following command using TeraTerm macro:

```
ubus call uci add '{"config":"wireless", "type":"wifi-iface", "name": "default_radio11"}'
```

so I am using the send command:

```
Send 'ubus call uci add '{"config":"wireless", "type":"wifi-iface", "name": "default_radio11"}''
```

The problem is that TeraTerm sends only `ubus call uci add` (since I have an apostrophe after add).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

You need to split the command:

```
send 'ubus call uci add '
send #39
send '{"config":"wireless", "type":"wifi-iface", "name": "default_radio11"}'
sendln #39
```

Note: #39 means ' in ASCII